# Editing junction table as subform via Form

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many, subform

I have following tables:

```
Course table:
CourseID(primary key) + (first field in combo box)
CourseName(second field in combo box)
CourseDescription

Students table(source for Main form):
StudentID (primary key)
StudentName
StudentPhone
StudentEmail


Enrollments table(junction table and source for subForm)
CourseID (foreign key referencing the Courses table) + made into combo box that stores selected value into CourseID
StudentID (foreign key referencing the Students table)

Both fields in Enrollments table are primary keys
```

[image: General idea]

I hope that the fact everything is in polish will not bother you.
I would like to assign Student selected in Main form to X amount of courses via SubForm but it won't let me edit IdKlient(IdCourses). Error states: `can't edit this control, it's related with auto increment field "IdKlient"(IdCourses)`

Comment: Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables. IdKlient in Enrollments looks like an autonumber field and should be Number Long Integer. User does not need to see the IdKlient fields. The Kurs combobox should set ColumnWidths like `0 cm;20 cm` to hide the CourseID and allow typing and display of course name in box. Are forms bound to table or query as RecordSource?

Comment: @June7  IdKlient in Enrollments isn't autonumber but as integer(same for IdKurs). As for idKlient being visible it's something I'm gonna change later. Main form is bound to table (Students), subform is bound to queary.

Comment: Well, your image shows IdKlient is autonumber in subform. I expect you have textbox bound to wrong field from query. Bind to table instead of query.

Comment: @June7 not sure what was exacly subform source but Indead IdKlient's pressance was main issue. After removing it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I found that unchecking "cascade delete Related Records" in relationships between Courses and Students to Enrollments table fixed the issue and gave me disired effect.